Multiplicative bases, path algebras, and Ext algebras
I am interested in understanding when a multiplicative basis exists for finite dimensional algebras over an algebraically closed field, and, in particular, Ext-algebras that are finite dimensional.
It appears there are two definitions of "multiplicative basis" that get thrown around for an algebra $A$ or an algebraically closed field $k$:

The first one I've seen says that a basis $I \subset A$ is a multiplicative basis, if and only if $a \cdot b \in I$ whenever $a, b\in I$;
The second is that $I \subset A$ is a basis if and only if $a \cdot b \in I \cup \{0 \}$ whenever $a, b\in I$;

I am interested in the second definition (which obviously could be equivalent to the first if we include zero in the basis).
Now, I understand from reading around that having a multiplicative basis for an algebra is a relatively strong condition, though it does exist for several one known families of algebras (finite type algebras in particular). However, can one not just use the paths of an equivalent path algebra to provide a basis? In particular, let's say our algebra is Koszul for simplicity, take the basis to be all paths of length $0,1$, and this should provide the basis.
Could someone let me know where I might be going wrong?
As a bonus, if you have any references for writing down bases of Ext algebras, please point me in that direction! Thank you in advance!

The problem is the algebra is equivalent to a quiver with relations and the relations make the paths no longer independent in general.
